# Passing pointer to function value not changing

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(int*);
int main()
{
    int i = 97, *p = &i;
    foo(p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    getch();
}

void foo(int *p)
{
    int j = 2;
    p = &j;
    printf("%d ", *p);
}
```

Output is 2 97
Why not 2 2 ?
pointer p holds the address of j now so why 97 is printed ?

Comment: `p` is still passed by value, being a pointer doesn't give it any magic powers :)

Comment: pointer `p` in function `foo()` is a copy of pointer `p` in the function `main()`. Use `int **p` but you will have a lifetime problem. Because `j` don't live in `main()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can imagine the function call and its definition the following way. For clarity I'll rename the function parameter as `q`.

```
foo(p);

void foo( /*int *q*/ )
{
    int *q = p;
    int j = 2;
    q = &j;
    printf("%d ", *q);
}
```

As it is seen the function parameter (in this case `q`) is a local variable of the function that is initialized by the value of an argument (in this case by the value of the argument `p`)

So any changes of the local variable (`q`) do not influence on the original argument (`p`).

After exiting the function the local variable will not be alive.

If you want to change the argument itself you should pass it by reference. For example

```
void foo( int **p )
{
    int j = 2;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

However after exiting the function the original argument/variable `p` will be invalid because it stores the address of a non-alive local variable of the function `j`.

So an attempt to access the memory that was occupied by the function's local variable `j` results in undefined behavior of the program.

You could make the program correct by declaring the local variable `j` as having static storage duration. For example

```
void foo( int **p )
{
    static int j = 2;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

and call the function like

```
foo(&p);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `foo`, you assign a new value to `p`.  However this is a *copy* of the value of `p` in `main`, so the change is not visible in main.

If you *dereferenced* `p`, then it would change the value if `i` in main:

```
void foo(int *p)
{
    *p = 2;
    printf("%d ", *p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = &j;
```

just changes the value of the local variable `p`. This has no effect on the caller's `p` variable (because `p` was passed by value) or the variable that `p` previously pointed to (because you didn't indirect through it). If you want to change the caller's data, write:

```
*p = j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the above code line by line. Here I have written comments as control passes through each of the lines...

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(int*);
int main()
{
    int i = 97, *p = &i;   //Lets assume i has address 2000  
    foo(p);                //p contains 2000 which is passed to foo. go to foo at 1.
    printf("%d ", *p);    // when control comes back no change to p it 
                          //still points to 2000 which stores 97 
    getch();
}

void foo(int *p) 1: // in foo another local variable p is created. 
                   //Let's call this lp. lp has now address 2000. i.e lp 
                   //and p both point to i but one locally exists in a 
                   // function and will be destroyed when control comes out 
                   // of the function 
{
    int j = 2;
    p = &j;        // now local p i.e lp points to another var j 
                   //  address. Suppose lp has address 3000 now.  
    printf("%d ", *p);  //val at address in lp is 2
}
```